# .NET Custom Strongly Typed HTML Helper with deep property navigation

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper, modelmetadata

I've searched all around, read all the posts related to creating a strongly typed helper, but none have addressed my issue. Problem:

When referencing a simple property, all works well:

```
@Html.TextBoxGroupFor(x => x.BadgeNumber)
```

When trying to access properties on a different class in my model, I get an error:

```
@Html.TextBoxGroupFor(x => x.Person.BadgeNumber)
```

The error is:

**The property InspectionEditViewModel.Person.BadgeNumber could not be found.**

The problem line is:

```
var metaData = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForProperty(() => Activator.CreateInstance<TModel>(), typeof(TModel), displayName);
```

I'm guessing it has to do with the GetMetadataForProperty not being able to find BadgeNumber on InspectionEditViewModel. MVC's HTML helpers by default are able to do this with no problems.

EDIT:

I knew I left something out, it's been a long day. Here is the Helpers code:

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxGroupFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper,
                                                     Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
        {
            var inputName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
            var fullHtmlFieldName = helper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(inputName);
            var metaData = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForProperty(() => Activator.CreateInstance<TModel>(), typeof(TModel), fullHtmlFieldName);
            var displayName = metaData.DisplayName ?? inputName;
            return TextBoxGroup(helper, displayName, inputName);
        }
```

Comment: Please post the definition of your HTML Helper method.

Comment: Can you show us the code you've written for your custom HTML Helper?

Comment: I know there has to be more to it - I've dug through the MVC framework helpers code but was not able to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(propertyExpression, html.ViewData);
```

This is what you are looking for. Unfortunately, this means that html must be an instance of HtmlHelper from a view whose model is the type you're trying to get the metadata for.

I think that's because it wants to take the property values from the Model/ViewData and pass it by the ModelMetadataProvider to allow it to to populate metadata specific to the model instance in question.

If you don't care about instance-specific metadata (eg: only want data annotation attributes) and so on, then just pass it a new ViewDataDictionary (where TModel is the type whose metadata you want to get).

For bonus feel-good points, the FromLambdaExpression method caches expressions and their resolved property paths inside it to give better performance.

Hope that helps you.